# Is there any way to compile a python script to web like unity webgl

Tags: python, pygame, web, unity-webgl

I've been working on a game in pygame for a while and decided it was too much of a hassle to compile it to all the operating systems. So, naturally, I turned to the web. While I am well aware that you can use Django or some other library to integrate python code into a website, I'm trying to make it so I can publish it to `itch.io`. To get to the point, I'd like to know if you can convert a python script to be used on the web a bit like Unity Web-GL.

Comment: Yes it does thanks very much!

Comment: Glad it helped, good luck with your game!